Dart Installation Error, An error occurred during installation
Downloading package from source 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
dart-sdk not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 Unable to obtain lock file access on 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\7e281caf1faf22254b2ad63a26e0a96dcaaf5012' for operations on 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\dart-sdk'. This may mean that a different user or administrator is holding this lock and that this process does not have permission to access it. If no other process is currently performing an operation on this file it may mean that an earlier NuGet process crashed and left an inaccessible lock file, in this case removing the file 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\7e281caf1faf22254b2ad63a26e0a96dcaaf5012' will allow NuGet to continue.
dart-sdk package files install failed with exit code 1. Performing other installation steps.
The install of dart-sdk was NOT successful.
dart-sdk not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 Unable to obtain lock file access on 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\7e281caf1faf22254b2ad63a26e0a96dcaaf5012' for operations on 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\dart-sdk'. This may mean that a different user or administrator is holding this lock and that this process does not have permission to access it. If no other process is currently performing an operation on this file it may mean that an earlier NuGet process crashed and left an inaccessible lock file, in this case removing the file 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\7e281caf1faf22254b2ad63a26e0a96dcaaf5012' will allow NuGet to continue.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - dart-sdk (exited 1) - dart-sdk not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 Unable to obtain lock file access on 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\7e281caf1faf22254b2ad63a26e0a96dcaaf5012' for operations on 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\dart-sdk'. This may mean that a different user or administrator is holding this lock and that this process does not have permission to access it. If no other process is currently performing an operation on this file it may mean that an earlier NuGet process crashed and left an inaccessible lock file, in this case removing the file 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\7e281caf1faf22254b2ad63a26e0a96dcaaf5012' will allow NuGet to continue.

There is an Error while Installing the Drat SDK, I have Tried more times But this Error Occurs Every time, Help me to solve this Error
I have used choco install dart-sdk for installing the the dart SDK, Every time this Error happening.

Have you tried restart your computer and tried again? Looks like some file-locking is going on by e.g. you have used multiple instances of choco at the same time by accident.
